# Estimating a probability density function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that $X$ is continuous random variable, taking values in a finite interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, with unknown pdf $f$.
Let $x_1, ..., x_n$ be an i.i.d sample of $X$.
Let $\hat{f}$ be a histogram estimator defined as
$$
\hat{f} := (\hat{f_1}, ..., \hat{f_k})
$$
$$
\hat{f} := (n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i \in I_1\}, ..., n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i \in I_k\})
$$
with $k$ fixed and let $I = \bigcup_{j=1}^kI_j$ be a partition.

(1) Calculate $E(\hat{f}) = (E(\hat{f_1}), ..., E(\hat{f_k}))$.
(2) Which parameters is $\hat{f}$ an unbiased estimator of?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to get the expectation of the estimated pdf, i.e. expectation of $\hat{f_1}$. I've written it as $E(\hat{f_1}) = \frac{1}{n}\int x\sum_1^n 1\{x\in I_1\} dx$. Not sure it's right, but if right, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: try to evaluate the expectations for $n=1$.  Also, in the first definition of $\widehat f$ $n$ should be $k$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:
$$E(\hat{f}_1) = E \left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1\{x_i \in I_1\}\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E\left[1\{x_i \in I_1\}\right]$$
(why are these steps justified?)

Hint 2: Write each $E[1\{x_i \in I_1\}]$ as a probability of a certain event.

Hint 3: The answer to question (2) is essentially what you get in question (1).